# List of tuples to nested dictionary based on tuple's values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Given a list of tuples like

```
[(1, 'Japan', 1, 'Tokyo'), (1, 'Japan', 2, 'Osaka'), (2, 'Korea', 1, 'Seoul',), (2, 'Korea', 2, 'Pyongyang')]
# country_id, country_name, city_id, city_name
```

I wish to structure it into this:

```
{
  'countries': [
    {
      'country_id': 1,
      'country_name': 'Japan',
      'cities': [
        {
          'city_id': 1,
          'city_name': 'Tokyo'
        },
        {
          'city_id': 2,
          'city_name': 'Osaka'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'country_id': 2,
      'country_name': 'Korea',
      'cities': [
        {
          'city_id': 1,
          'city_name': 'Seoul'
        },
        {
          'city_id': 2,
          'city_name': 'Pyongyang'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I implemented this and it works well, but is not Pythonic. Wondering if this can be greatly refined/sped up since this forms the response of an API.

```
x = [(1, 'Japan', 1, 'Tokyo'), (1, 'Japan', 2, 'Osaka'), (2, 'Korea', 1, 'Seoul'), (2, 'Korea', 2, 'Pyongyang')]
countrylist = []
query_countries = []
for a in x:
    if a[0] not in countrylist:
        query_countries.append((a[0], a[1]))
        countrylist.append(a[0])
countrylist = list(set(countrylist))
countries =  [{'country_id': r[0], 'country_name': r[1], 'cities': []} for r in query_countries]
for r in x:
    countries[countrylist.index(r[0])]['cities'].append({'city_id': r[2], 'city_name': r[3]})
final = {'countries': countries}
print(final)
#{'countries': [{'country_id': 1, 'country_name': 'Japan', 'cities': [{'city_id': 1, 'city_name': 'Tokyo'}, {'city_id': 2, 'city_name': 'Osaka'}]}, {'country_id': 2, 'country_name': 'Korea', 'cities': [{'city_id': 1, 'city_name': 'Seoul'}, {'city_id': 2, 'city_name': 'Pyongyang'}]}]}
```

Comment: look at pydash module, it has options for grouping, ordering etc

Comment: Please show your attempt, and ask about the specific problem you have with it (something something appending dictionary in list…).

Comment: To get your question re-opened, provide information as to why you cannot do it. What is the problem you encountered when trying to do this? Add your code; explain how it does not work.

Comment: What does "this takes a hit because of being iterative" mean?

Comment: Why pseudo code? Are you looking for pseudo code? I would suggest you post the actual code you have tried with, and point out exactly what is going wrong, in a way we can reproduce.

Comment: All feedback implemented. Hope it's good enough now.

Comment: Yes, this looks good now. Now wait until the question gets enough votes to be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions `a[0] not in countrylist` and `countrylist.index(r[0])` are not the most efficient, as `countrylist` is a list and these operations require the list to be scanned. At some point you turn it into a set, but you could have decided to use a set from the start all the way to the end, and then these lookup operations could be done in constant time (on average). This would already improve performance for large inputs.

For this kind of challenge, `groupby` and `itemgetter` seem good tools to use. They allow to get the job done with one expression:

```
data = [(1, 'Japan', 1, 'Tokyo'), (1, 'Japan', 2, 'Osaka'), (2, 'Korea', 1, 'Seoul',), (2, 'Korea', 2, 'Pyongyang')]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

result = [
    {
        "country_id": country_id,
        "country_name": country_name,
        "cities": [
            {
                "city_id": city_id,
                "city_name": city_name
            } for *_, city_id, city_name in cities
        ]
    } for (country_id, country_name), cities in groupby(data, itemgetter(0, 1))
]

print(result)
```

### `groupby`

You can imagine this `groupby` call to return this structure:

```
[
    (1, 'Japan'), [
        (1, 'Japan', 1, 'Tokyo'), 
        (1, 'Japan', 2, 'Osaka')
    ],
    (2, 'Korea'), [
        (2, 'Korea', 1, 'Seoul'),
        (2, 'Korea', 2, 'Pyongyang')
    ]
]
```

...except that the lists are not lists but iterators. But for a `for ... in` syntax that makes no difference.

The inner tuples are just references to the original data, while the values in the outer layer (the groups) are produced by `itemgetter`, which produces tuples of the first two values.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been reading the documentation for `itemgetter` and `groupby` and trying to break this down, but I am unable to figure out how particularly the `<itertools._grouper>` object that `groupby` provides can be used to create and populate the dictionaries. Is a breakdown available?

Comment: See addition to answer.